# Jump Attack Freeze With Ninja Pygame In Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a simple ninja game that has a scrolling background. You can slide with down arrow. Jump with up arrow, and if you are at the start of the jump you can press the right arrow to jump attack. The problem is you can hold the right arrow while in the arrow and the ninja just freezes.

I don't know how to fix this so help would be appreciated.

Sorry for long code but this is the code:

```
import pygame
import time
x = 60
y = 400
pygame.init()
Counter  = 0
jumpCount = 10
imagerun = 0
imageslide = 0
imagejump = 0
imageattack = 0
slow = 0
jumppower =6.5
isslide = False
isjump = False
isattack = False
ninjaheight = 192
ninjawidth = 192
ninjaheight2 = ninjaheight + 50
ninjawidth2 = ninjawidth + 50
winwidth = 1200
winheight = 600
isrunning = True
repeat = 0
score = 0
def redrawgame():
    global imageattack
    global score
    global isrunning
    win.blit(bg, (bgX, 0))  # draws our first bg image
    win.blit(bg, (bgX2, 0))
    if isrunning == True:
        win.blit(Run[imagerun],(x, y))
    if isslide == True:
        isrunning = False
        win.blit(Slide[imageslide],(x, y))
    if isjump == True and isattack == False:
        win.blit(Jump[imagejump],(x, y))
    if isattack == True:
        if imageattack == 9:
            imageattack = 0
        win.blit(Attack[imageattack],(x, y))
    score += 1
    largeFont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 65) # Font object
    text = largeFont.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (0 ,0 ,255)) # create our text
    win.blit(text, (840, 25)) # draw the text to the screen
    pygame.display.update()


bg = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('bg.png'),(winwidth, winheight))
bgX = 0
bgX2 = bg.get_width()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((winwidth, winheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
Run = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__0.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__1.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__2.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__3.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__4.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__5.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__6.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__7.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__8.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Run__9.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth))]
Slide = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__0.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__1.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__2.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__3.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__4.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__5.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__6.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__7.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__8.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Slide__9.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth))]  
Jump = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump.png'), (ninjaheight, ninjawidth))]
Attack = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__0.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__1.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__2.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__3.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__4.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__5.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__6.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__7.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__8.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2)), pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__9.png'), (ninjaheight2, ninjawidth2))]
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    time.sleep(0.020)
    Counter += 1
    if slow == 0:
        slow +=1
    elif slow == 1:
        slow -= 1
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()   
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        if not isslide == True:
                if Counter > 39:
                    if jumpCount == 10:
                        isrunning = False
                        isjump = False
                        isslide = True
                        Counter = 0
                        imageslide = 0

    if isrunning == True:
        if imagerun == 9:
            imagerun = 0
        else:
            imagerun +=1

    if isslide == True:
        if imageslide == 9:
            if repeat == 1:
                isslide = False
                isrunning = True
                imageslide = 0
                repeat = 0
            else:
                repeat +=1
                imageslide = 0
        else:
            imageslide += 1

    if not (isjump):
        if Counter > 1:
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                isjump = True
                isrunning = False
                isslide = False
                Counter = 30
    else:
        if jumpCount < 0: #if negative
            jumpCount -=1
            y -=jumpCount *jumppower
            if slow == 1:
                imageattack += 1
            if jumpCount == -9:
                isjump = False
                jumpCount = 10
                isattack = False
                imageattack = 0
        else:

            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                if jumpCount > 6:
                    if not (isattack):
                        isattack = True
                        imageattack = 0
                        Counter = 30
                        jumpCount -= 1
                        y -= jumpCount *jumppower
            else:
                if jumpCount < 0: #if negative
                    jumpCount -=1
                    y -=jumpCount *jumppower
                    if slow == 1:
                        imageattack += 1
                    if jumpCount == -9:
                        jump = False
                        jumpCount = 10
                        isattack = False
                        imageattack = 0
                else:  
                    jumpCount -= 1
                    y -= jumpCount *jumppower
                    if slow == 1:
                        imageattack += 1

    bgX -= 15.4  # Move both background images back
    bgX2 -= 15.4
    if bgX < bg.get_width() * -1:  # If our bg is at the -width then reset its position
        bgX = bg.get_width() 
    if bgX2 < bg.get_width() * -1:
        bgX2 = bg.get_width()
    redrawgame()
    if isslide == False and isjump ==  False and isattack == False:
        isrunning = True       
pygame.quit()
```

I hope that if you hold down the right button it will do the same as just tapping it once. Thanks for the help, Andrew.

Comment: What have you done to try and debug this issue so far? If you surround suspect blocks of code with print statements `print( <linenumber> )` you can find sections of code that are being run (or not run) at the wrong times.


Also, while having the entire code is good for context, linebreaks and comments really help when trying to read through it.

Comment: You are trying to do to much everywhere and it’s a mess. My advice(maybe not fun) is to start from a clean state, and implement one thing at a time and check if that work before moving on.

Comment: you have mess in code and mainloop is too long. Put code in functions and classes and put them before `pygame.init()` - and then code will be more readable. You should also learn how to use [pygame.spirte.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) or at least [pygame.Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) which has methods to check collisions. [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/)

Comment: Thanks for help, I kinda fixed the code, I agree it was messy but It is a little less messy now. I added comments and stuff to help people understand it, thanks for help though.

Comment: Your `Attack` line is 949 characters long and you load images named sequentially. Consider using a `for` loop to load them. Also, if you fixed the problem you can post an answer to your own question and mark it as answered

Answer (score -1):

I can't run it and it is not solution for problem with jumping.

It only shows how to make it more readable. It split code in functions `update_xxx` and `draw_xxx` - like `update_attack()`, draw_attac()`, 'update_bg()`, `draw_bg()`. This way `mainloop` is shorter.

Now it should be easier to search problem in code.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WIN_WIDTH = 1200
WIN_HEIGHT = 600

NINJA_WIDTH = 192
NINJA_HEIGHT = 192
NINJA_WIDTH_2 = NINJA_WIDTH + 50
NINJA_HEIGHT_2 = NINJA_HEIGHT + 50

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

def draw_bg():
    win.blit(bg, (bg_x1, 0))  # draws our first bg image
    win.blit(bg, (bg_x2, 0))

def draw_text():
    text = large_ont.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (0 ,0 ,255)) # create our text
    win.blit(text, (840, 25)) # draw the text to the screen

def draw_running():
    win.blit(run_images[run_index], (x, y))

def draw_slide():
    win.blit(slide_images[slide_index], (x, y))

def draw_attack():
    win.blit(attack_images[attack_index], (x, y))

def update_bg():
    global bg_x1
    global bg_x2

    bg_x1 -= 15.4  # Move both background images back
    bg_x2 -= 15.4

    if bg_x1 < -bg.get_width():  # If our bg is at the -width then reset its position
        bg_x1 = bg.get_width() 
    if bg_x2 < -bg.get_width():
        bg_x2 = bg.get_width()

def update_running():
    global run_indes

    if run_index == 9:
        run_index = 0
    else:
        run_index +=1

def update_slide():
    global slide_index
    global is_slide
    global is_running
    global repeat

    is_running = False

    if slide_index == 9:
        if repeat == 1:
            is_slide = False
            is_running = True
            slide_index = 0
            repeat = 0
        else:
            repeat += 1
            slide_index = 0
    else:
        slide_index += 1

def update_attack()
    global image_index

    if image_index == 9:
        image_index = 0

def update_jump():
    global jump_count
    global x, y
    global attack_index
    global is_jump
    global is_attack
    global counter

    if jump_count < 0: #if negative
        jump_count -=1
        y -= jump_count *jump_power
        if slow == 1:
            attack_index += 1
        if jump_count == -9:
            is_jump = False
            jump_count = 10
            is_attack = False
            attack_index = 0
    else:
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if jump_count > 6:
                if not is_attack:
                    is_attack = True
                    attack_index = 0
                    counter = 30
                    jump_count -= 1
                    y -= jump_count * jump_power
        else:
            if jump_count < 0: #if negative
                jump_count -=1
                y -= jump_count *jump_power
                if slow == 1:
                    attack_index += 1
                if jump_count == -9:
                    jump = False
                    jump_count = 10
                    is_attack = False
                    attack_index = 0
            else:  
                jump_count -= 1
                y -= jump_count *jump_power
                if slow == 1:
                    attack_index += 1

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

# - init -
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
win_rect = win.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

# - objects -
x = 60
y = 400

counter  = 0
jump_count = 10

slow = 0
jump_power =6.5
is_slide = False
is_jump = False
is_attack = False
is_running = True
repeat = 0
score = 0

run_index = 0
slide_index = 0
jump_index = 0
attack_index = 0

#

large_font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 65)

bg = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('bg.png'), (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
bg_x1 = 0
bg_x2 = bg.get_width()


run_images = []
for i in range(10):
    img = pygame.image.load('Run__{}.png'.format(i))
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (NINJA_WIDTH, NINJA_HEIGHT)),
    run_images.append(img)

slide_images = []
for i in range(10):
    img = pygame.image.load('Slide__{}.png'.format(i))
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (NINJA_WIDTH, NINJA_HEIGHT)),
    slide_images.append(img)

jump_images = [
    pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Jump.png'), (NINJA_WIDTH, NINJA_HEIGHT))
]

attack_images = []
for i in range(10):
    img = pygame.image.load('Jump_Attack__{}.png'.format(i))
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (NINJA_WIDTH_2, NINJA_HEIGHT_2)),
    slide_images.append(img)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True

while run:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # - updates (without draws) -

    counter += 1

    if slow == 0:
        slow +=1
    elif slow == 1:
        slow -= 1

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        if not is_slide:
            if counter > 39:
                if jump_count == 10:
                    is_running = False
                    is_jump = False
                    is_slide = True
                    counter = 0
                    slide_index = 0

    if is_running:
        update_running()

    if is_slide:
        update_slide()

    if isjump:
        update_jump()
    else:
        if counter > 1:
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                is_jump = True
                is_running = False
                is_slide = False
                counter = 30

    if is_attack:
        update_attack()

    update_bg()

    score += 1

    # - draws (without updates) -

    draw_bg()

    if is_running:
        draw_running()

    if is_slide:
        draw_slide()

    if is_jump and is_attack:
        win.blit(jump_images[jump_index], (x, y))

    if is_attack:
        draw_attack()

    draw_text()

    pygame.display.update()

    # - others -

    if not is_slide and not is_jump and not is_attack:
        is_running = True

    # - speed -

    clock.ticks(30) # speed 30 FPS

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```